# How to fix a Package Manager Error in notification area after upgrading a fresh install of lucid with a '/home' from Jaunty?

Tags: 10.04, package-management

I just installed 10.04, and used manual partitioning to preserve my '/home' from a 9.04 install. (To be clear: I did not upgraded 9.04 to 10.04, but installed 10.04 off a of CD, keeping only my '/home'.) After the sucessful 10.04 install, I used synaptic to apply all updates, rebooted, removed some packages (mostly tomboy and bluetooth), rebooted, and then used synaptic to install tonnes of packages, mostly from `lucid/main` and `lucid-updates/main`, though I also did install a number from `lucid/universe` and `lucid-updates/universe`.

A minute or so after the mass installation of new packages, a red circular icon with a white bar running horizontally through it appeared in my notification area. (The icon is quite like the "Do not enter this road" sign pictured [here](http://www.mto.gov.on.ca/english/dandv/driver/handbook/section3.1.1.shtml).) On hovering my mouse over the icon, I get the following message:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: 'Unknown Error: '' (E:Opening configuration file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99synaptic - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied))' This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies

(Since there was no way to copy the text, I transcribed it; it isn't impossible that it is not a completely faithful transcription.)

I then ran the following commands:

1. `sudo apt-get check`
2. `sudo apt-get clean`
3. `sudo apt-get autoclean`
4. `sudo apt-get autoremove`

and then ran those same commands (in that order) but also with the `-f` flag. I then rebooted. This hasn't removed the warning icon from the notification area. So, I am at a loss for how to proceed.

[Snip a lot of detail about what packages I'd installed and removed that turned out not to be relevant at all.]

Comment: When you say you use synaptic to apply all updates, do you mean after the new installation of 10.04?

Comment: @txwikinger: Yes. Off to edit to make that clear in the question.

Comment: Can you post what is in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99synaptic` you can find it by pressing Alt+F2 and then typing `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99synaptic` Please post it to http://pastebin.com and link it back to there ;)

Comment: @Source Lab: See my comment on @Oli's answer if interested. The file has almost no contents and it was a silly permissions problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should fix the permission problem ([from this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1536078)):

```
sudo chmod o+r /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99synaptic
```

But usually if you have broken dependencies you'd look in synaptic, aptitude or fire off:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Doing `ls -l /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` revealed that all files in that dir had `root:root` ownership and `rw-r--r--` permissions, save `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99synaptic`. Running `sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99synaptic` fixed the problem as in @Oli's link. `99synaptic` has a single line `APT::Install-Recommends "true";`. It's not at all clear why this needs to be world readable for things to function smoothly, nor why the permissions on `99synaptic` should have been different than those of the other files in the dir. But, problem solved! Thanks!